# Django: Query where GenericRelation is null

Tags: python, django

I'd like to query a model for instances where the generic relation field is not empty (that is, in the example below I'm looking for instances where document.count() > 0):

```
class Report(models.Model):
    document   = generic.GenericRelation(Document)
```

Something like:

```
Report.objects.filter(date__gte=twomonths).exclude(document__isnull=True)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work - the query returns objects that have no "document" (ie. it returns objects where document.count() is 0).

Is there a way to query for instances where the generic relationship is empty?

Answer (score 2):

I believe there still may be some contradictions in your question. Note: "I'm looking for instances where document.count() == 0" and then later, "Unfortunately this doesn't work - the query returns objects that have no 'document' (ie. it returns objects where document.count() is 0)".

If you want `Report`s that have *no* documents, you can use:

```
Report.objects.filter(document__isnull=True)
```

Or

```
Report.objects.exclude(document__isnull=False)
```

If you want `Report`s that have *at least one* document, you can use:

```
Report.objects.filter(document__isnull=False)
```

Or

```
Report.objects.exclude(document__isnull=True)
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but the query doesn't work: FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'content_type' into field. Choices are: ... . None of the listed choices seem correct as content_type or object_id.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. Saw `GenericRelation` but thought `GenericForeignKey`. But now I'm confused. What do you mean by "where the relation is empty" if it's not also where document.count() is `0`?

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry, I realize I worded it in a confusing way - note the "exclude", so really I'm looking to exclude cases where document.count() == 0 .